# I am not able to do my first web socket as it returns a closed connection

Tags: python, websocket

```
import WebSocket

SOCKET = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/ethusdt@kline_1M"


def on_open(ws):
    print('opened connection')


def on_close(ws):
    print('closed connection')


def on_message(ws, message):
    print('received message')
    print(message)


ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open=on_open, on_close=on_close,on_message=on_message)
ws.run_forever()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're trying to interface with Binance.
There's the [python-binance library](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/websockets.html).
It's fairly well documented and should handle everything you're trying to do.